# How to process XML file referenced in input XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, reference, include

Suppose I have in my input XML file a reference (URL) to another XML file. I'd like to process this referenced XML file as if it were the input of my stylesheet/template. How do I do that?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple and standard solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the standard XSLT [`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document) function, like this**:

```
<xsl:template match="someElementContainingURL">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="document(string(.))" mode="doc2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

In the example above, we suppose that in the source XML document an element named `someElementContainingURL` (substitute this by the actual element name in your specific XML document) contains the URL to a second document that you want to process.

Within the template matching `someElementContainingURL` we apply templates to the result of the `document()` function when passed as argument the string value of the current node. It is best to organize the processing of the second document in a different mode, so that identical node names and node types from the two documents can be processed by different templates, avoiding conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('document.xml')/rootnode/subnode" />
<xsl:copy-of select="document('http://example.com/document.xml')/rootnode/subnode" />
```